# how to (still) use a wildcard in the middle of a string?

Tags: splunk

I am trying to run the following query

```
index=one /thispath/file*.pdf
```

I know that using wildcards in the middle of a string is not recommended, but  I have too many different files: `file001.pdf`, `fileabc.pdf` and others.

What can I do? I am more worried about bogus results than processing speed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended, but it works.  Just do it.

```
index=one "/thispath/file*.pdf"
```

Comment: thanks but why do they say unexpected results then?

Comment: Where are you reading about unexpected results?
I think it depends on context, but I don't recall ever having a problem with embedded wildcards (although I try to avoid them).

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do this one of 3 ways, actually, depending on your needs:

```
| makeresults | eval field="/thispath/fileone.pdf"
```

1. tell splunk to look for both the beginning and end of something

   ```
   | search field="/thispath/file*" AND field="*.pdf"
   ```
2. filter after the event search using wildcards

   ```
   | where like(field, "/thispath/file%.pdf")
   ```
3. filter after the event search using regex

   ```
   | where match(field, "/thispath/file.*.pdf")
   ```